# Combining heredoc and input redirection in Bash vs ZSH

Tags: bash, zsh, cat, io-redirection, heredoc

The following code works on ZSH with no issue, combining the heredoc with the content of the file test.csv:

```
cat <<EOF <test.csv
id,name,age
EOF
```

How can I write the same command in Bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(<file)` will work in both Bash and Zsh:

```sh
cat <<EOF
id,name,age
$(<test.csv)
EOF
```

It will also work in Ksh (from where I believe it comes and was ported to Bash and Zsh). It behaves as `$(cat file)` except it will not call out to `cat` and will be handled completely by the shell itself.

It is described in Bash documentation [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) section:

> The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [@blami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118999/1126841), you can use `cat` twice in a command group (trading the memory needed to store all of `test.csv` in memory for the time it takes to run `cat` a second time).

```
{
  cat <<EOF
  id,name,age
EOF

  cat test.csv
}
```

or, since the here document is so short, use a process substitution (which still forks another process):

```
cat <(echo "id,name,age") test.csv
```

Comment: I learned by surprise, that zsh allows additive input redirection (for instance, I found that both `cat <foo.x <bar.x` and `cat <<<uuu <foo.x` both output all of their input-redirections). Do you know by chance, where this is documented? I looked at the man page, section _REDIRECTION_, but didn't find this mentioned.

Comment: That's a here-string you are talking about. It is in ZSH's official docs: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html. For instance, this works in ZSH: `cat <<<"id,name,age" <test.csv`. But if the question is about the multiple input redirection that happens under ZSH (supposedly not posix-compatible), I am also wondering about it. In the above link you can read, though, that "If the result of substitution on _word_ produces more than one filename, redirection occurs for each separate filename in turn."

Comment: `zsh` *can* be POSIX-compatible, but the default settings are far, far from it. There is an option (`MULTIO`, on by default) that allows multiple redirections to all be handled (rather than the POSIX behavior of only using the last one processed). I did not know about the multiple-filename behavior of a single redirection before.